# How to access link slave table ID in go

Tags: linux, go, netlink

Using https://godoc.org/github.com/vishvananda/netlink, I'm trying to access the table ID of a link that has been set as a slave to a VRF.  If I add the link and then get it, I can see that the `Slave` field of `netlink.LinkAttrs` is set; printing it using "%+v" it prints as `{Table:2}`, which is correct.  But I can't figure out how to access the `Table` field.

In `LinkAttrs`, `Slave` appears as a field (included interface):

```
type LinkAttrs struct {
    ...
    Slave SlaveType
}
```

`SlaveType` is an interface:

```
type LinkSlave interface {
    SlaveType() string
}
```

The value of `link.Attrs().Slave.SlaveType()` is "vrf", implying that the struct that implements `SlaveType` and is assigned to `Slave` is possibly the `netlink.Vrf` type, but that type doesn't implement `SlaveType`.  So, of course, trying to type-assert fails:

```
vrf, ok := link.Slave.(netlink.Vrf) // or .*(netlink.Vrf)
```

as "impossible assertion", which is what I expect since Vrf doesn't implement SlaveType.

I can't find any type that does other than `BondSlave`, which has many more fields (and no `Table` field.)

The only struct with a Table field is

```
type Vrf struct {
    LinkAttrs
    Table uint32
}
```

So, I'm at a loss on how to access the `Table` field.

Example, which I run using `sudo -E --preserve-env=PATH bash -c "go test"`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"

    "github.com/vishvananda/netlink"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
)

var vrfConfig = &netlink.Vrf{
    LinkAttrs: netlink.LinkAttrs{
        Name:  "vrf1"},
    Table: 2,
}

var link1Config = &netlink.Gretap{
    LinkAttrs: netlink.LinkAttrs{
        Name:      "link1"},
    Remote: []byte{1, 1, 1, 1},
}

func TestSlave(t *testing.T) {
    err := netlink.LinkAdd(vrfConfig)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    err = netlink.LinkAdd(link1Config)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    err = netlink.LinkSetMaster(link1Config, vrfConfig)
    require.NoError(t, err)

    links, err := netlink.LinkList()
    require.NoError(t, err)

    for _, link := range links {
        if link.Attrs().Name == "link1" {
            fmt.Printf("Slave: %+v\n", link.Attrs().Slave)
        }
    }
}
```

(See https://goplay.tools/snippet/mHaMt9jRs9_m , but of course it returns a permission error.)

Clean up using

```
sudo ip link delete vrf1; sudo ip link delete link1
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `undefined: netlink.Geneve`